# Saving Image From HTML page To The NetSuite File Cabinet throw UNEXPECTED_ERROR

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I have a suitelet that creates a html page. This page has a html element input type file. I am trying to take that file and upload it to the file cabinet. This is not done on a NetSuite form so the file element is not a netsuite file object.

The javascript on the HTML page is as follows

```
function uploadPhotoToNetSuite(){
var bookingid = $("#txtAddPhotoBookingId").val();
var caseid = $("#txtAddPhotoCaseId").val();
var isCase = caseid != "";

var base64Image = document.getElementById("imageToAdd").src;
var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("operations", 'uploadphoto');
    formData.append("bookingid", bookingid);
    formData.append("caseid", caseid);
    formData.append("image", base64Image);    

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        var objResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(!objResponse.uploadphoto.success){
            alert(objResponse.uploadphoto.err);
        } else {
            closeLoading();
        }
        clearPhotoUpload();
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", stAPIURL, true);
loading("Uploading Photo");
xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Then this matches to a method in my suitelet as follows.

```
function uploadPhoto(params, recUser){
    try{
        var imageFolder = 767406;
        var thePhoto = params.image;
        var filetype = "png";
        if(thePhoto.indexOf("image/png") > -1) filetype = "png";
        var theFile = file.create({
            name: 'test.' + filetype,
            fileType: filetype == "jpg" ? file.Type.JPGIMAGE : file.Type.PNGIMAGE,
            contents: thePhoto,
            description: 'This is a plain text file.',
            encoding: file.Encoding.UTF8,
            folder: imageFolder,
            isOnline: true
        });
        var id = theFile.save();
    } catch(err){
        return {
            success : false,
            err : JSON.stringify(err)
        }
    }
    return {
        success : true
    }
}
```

When this is happens I am getting the error UNEXPECTED_ERROR. The variable thePhoto is a base64 string of the image.

**UPDATE:**

I change the suitelet code to create a text file and the file uploaded perfectly and the base64 string was in the text file. When I took that base64 string and put it through a convertor, the image I uploaded was the result.

With this in mind, I changed the code again to;

```
var theFile = file.create({
    name: 'test.jpg',
    fileType: file.Type.JPGIMAGE,
    contents: thePhoto,
    description: 'This is a plain text file.',
    encoding: file.Encoding.UTF8,
    folder: imageFolder,
    isOnline: true
});
```

And uploaded a .jpg file. Once again I got the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and finally figured out the resolution.  NetSuite does convert Base64 image data to a JPEG file in the file cabinet automatically, but it can only be the raw base64 data.  The base64 metadata at the beginning needs to be removed.  After several hours of frustration, adding the first two lines to the function below allowed it to save properly as a JPEG file (without the unexpected error).

```
function saveJPEGFile(fileName, fileContents){
    if (fileContents.startsWith('data:image/jpeg;base64'))
      fileContents=fileContents.substring('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
       
    log.debug('saving file:',`${fileName} : ${fileContents.length} : ${fileContents}`)
    var fileObj = file.create({
        name : fileName,
        fileType: file.Type.JPGIMAGE,
        contents: fileContents,
        folder :  1127
    });
    var fileId = fileObj.save();
       
}
```